# версии питона в линукс

Tags: linux, python-3.x

Недавно на линуксе(Mint). Установил кучу версий пайтона и теперь не могу с ними разобраться. 
`$ which python3` /usr/bin/python3, `$ which python3.7`, `$ which python3.6` /usr/bin/python3.6, `$ which python` /usr/bin/python.
Проблема в том что в атоме, где я практикуюсь, атом раннер(с поправленым конфигом "python": "python3") выдает sys.version Python 3.7.2. В консоле при $ python3 запускается Python 3.6.7. Pip вообще хз куда устанавливает пакеты и выбивало ошибку importError, но это я вроде пофиксил. Подскажите как это исправить, может удалить как-то другие версии питон? Я просто уже удалял неудачно так что пришлось ос переустанавливать.

Answer (score 2):

> может удалить как-то другие версии питон?

Способ удаления пакета зависит от способа его установки.

- Если Вы ставили пакетным менеджером, то удалять надо - пакетным менеджером
- Если ставили через pip - то и удалять надо с помощью pip.
- Ну а если сами, из сорцов... Тогда - Бог Вам в помощь!

> не могу с ними разобраться.

Есть ещё одна тонкость. Каждая версия питона использует СВОИ пакеты модулей.Установка пакета для одной версии вовсе не означает его наличие в другой. Поэтому, когда Вы устанавливаете/удаляете пакеты с помощью pip, указывайте явно версию:

- pip2
- pip3

А вообще-то, иметь несколько версий питона - большая головная боль. Понятно, что хочется иметь самую последнюю, но значительная часть ПО в репозитарии написана на втором питоне. Поэтому, после установки третьего они просто перестают работать.

Что бы избежать таких проблем, я в главных скриптах используемых приложений руками прописал версию питона явно.

Например, в библиотечной программе *Calibre* у меня явно указано в первой строке скрипта:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

И хотя, по дефаульту, у меня работает третий питон, но так конфликтов не возникает.

Answer (score 0):

Всё разобрался. Атом ставил из mintinstall, он какой-то сломанный был и не там искал python, переустановил из офф сайта и норм заработало, с версией python3.7-minimal, тоже из менеджера программ,  были проблемы с pip. Также переустановил и работает python3.7 -m pip install .